# python debug adapter not being found in vscode - WSL:Ubuntu

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to debug a python script in vscode using the [Remote WSL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl) extension with Python 3.9.1.

When I start debugging mode(F5), the below message is immediately shown:

> Couldn't find a debug adapter descriptor for debug type 'python' (extension might have failed to active)

The message offers me to **Open launch.json**, I still don't know what I have to change in my json file, below are my current settings:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "c:/<my_user_name>/projects",
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

What I have tried until now:

- Re-installed [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension and read the [doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl-tutorial). However the doc does not help to solve the issue at all. These steps has been already suggest in another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49607174/how-to-configure-vscode-to-debug-python-using-wsl) almost 3 years ago.
- Reload vscode in order to reload the extensions, as the error shows an extensions might have failed to active. No success.

Answer (score 2):

If you have VSCode, installed already before you could configure WSL, you could be facing this issue. Here's how I resolved it:

1. To the bottom left corner of VSCode, you may find the environment choice. Natively, this corresponds to windows, you might have to switch this to `Remote-WSL: New Window` which will open VSCode in a new window.
   [image]
2. In the debug tab of VSCode, you don't have to edit any configuration, except you need to define the location of your interpreter. In my case, I defined the location to be as my virtual environments' bin/ directory.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

In my case the debugging software was asking for an update. The message did appear at the settings icon on the bottom left.

Settings > install updates